# Unable to compute the determinant of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Find the determinant of the matrix

\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0&0&0 &2\\0&1&0&0&2&0
\\0&0&1&2&0&0\\0&0&2&1&0&0\\0&2&0&0&1&0\\2&0&0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}

I tried using Laplace Expansion

I got

\begin{bmatrix}
1& 0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1 &2&0 & 0\\2&1&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}-\begin{bmatrix}
1& 0\\0&2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 0 &1&2 & 0\\0&2&1&0\\2&0&0&0\\0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}-\begin{bmatrix}
0& 2\\1&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 0 &1&2 & 0\\0&2&1&0\\0&0&0&1\\2&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}
0& 2\\2&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 0 &0&1 & 2\\0&0&2&1\\0&2&0&0\\2&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}

The result I am getting is $-3+12-12+48=45

which is wrong

The correct answer is $-27$.

Please help where i am wrong.

**NOTE**:

Please dont give another method for solving this problems.I know there are many.

How to fix this problem

**EDIT**:

$(-1)^{1+1+2+2}$
\begin{bmatrix}
1& 0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1 &2&0 & 0\\2&1&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}
$+(-1)^{1+2+1+3}$\begin{bmatrix}
1& 0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 0 &0&2 & 0\\2&1&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}

+$(-1)^{1+2+1+4}$\begin{bmatrix}
1& 0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 0 &0&2 & 0\\1&2&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}+...

Comment: Recheck the last two signs.

Comment: @dxiv; I got it $(-1)^{+1+2+1+5}$

Comment: and the last one as $(-1)^{1+2+5+6}$

Comment: @dxiv; where do u find it wrong;Please help

Comment: @dxiv; will u kindly help

Comment: Not sure what flavor of Laplace expansion you are using, for example I'd write the third cofactor as $\begin{bmatrix}
1& 0\\0&2\end{bmatrix}$ rather than $\begin{bmatrix}
0& 2\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: @dxiv; i have edited d question to show u how I am expanding

Comment: @dxiv;can u help now;I really need help

Comment: $1 \cdot (-3) - 2 \cdot (-6) - (-2) \cdot 6 + (-4) \cdot 12 = -27$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let 
$$ 
I = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}, 
\qquad
A = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 2 \\
0 & 2 & 0 \\
2 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} 
$$
Then your matrix can be written as
$$
M = \begin{bmatrix}
I & A \\ A & I
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Then a [formular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Block_matrices) gives us
$$
\det M = \det I \cdot \det(I - A^2).
$$
Since
$$ 
I - A^2 = I - 4I = -3I,
$$
we conclude that
$$ \det M = -3^3 = -27.$$

Comment: (+1)   To make formula visible:
 $\ \ \det\begin{bmatrix}A& B\\ C& D\end{bmatrix} = \det(A) \det(D - C A^{-1} B) $

Answer (score 0):

We denote the given matrix by $A$ and the field over which we are working by $K$.

If $\operatorname{char}(K) = 2$ then $A$ is the identity matrix, and it follows that $\det(A) = 1$.

We now consider the case $\operatorname{char}(K) \neq 2$:
Note that the matrix
$$
    A + I
  = \begin{bmatrix}
      2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 \\
      0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\
      0 & 0 & 2 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\
      0 & 0 & 2 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\
      0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\
      2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2
    \end{bmatrix}
$$
has rank $3$, so that $\dim \ker(A + I) = 3$.
This shows that $-1$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ with multiplicity $3$.
Similarly, the matrix
$$
    A - 3I
  = \begin{bmatrix}
      -2  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0 &  2 \\
       0  & -2  &  0  &  0  &  2 &  0 \\
       0  &  0  & -2  &  2  &  0 &  0 \\
       0  &  0  &  2  & -2  &  0 &  0 \\
       0  &  2  &  0  &  0  & -2 &  0 \\
       2  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0 & -2
    \end{bmatrix}
$$
has rank $3$, so that $\dim \ker(A - 3I) = 3$.
This shows that $3$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ with multiplicity $3$.

We have that $-1 \neq 3$ because $\operatorname{char}(K) \neq 2$.
It follows that $A$ is diagonalizable with eigenvalues $-1, -1, -1, 3, 3, 3$.
The determianent $\det(A)$ is the product of these eigenvalues, so
$$
    \det(A)
  = (-1) \cdot (-1) \cdot (-1) \cdot 3 \cdot 3 \cdot 3
  = -27.
$$